# Android Firebase - Get data when user is not authenticated

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I would like to know if I can get data from the Firebase database even when the user is not authenticated.
I got few reasons for that. One of them is when the user registers for the first time and saves his data on the FirebaseDatabase. Once he logs out and wants to log in again, I want to skip the registration activity to the MainActivity.

**Here is an code example**

```
  public class FireBaseLoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private FirebaseUser currentUser;
    private DatabaseReference refToUsers;
    private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 1;


  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_fire_base_login);


      currentUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
      refToUsers = 
   FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child(Params.USERS);

          startSignIn();
     }
  }


      public void startSignIn(){
    List<AuthUI.IdpConfig> providers = Arrays.asList(
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.GOOGLE_PROVIDER)
                    .setPermissions(Arrays.asList(Scopes.PROFILE,Scopes.EMAIL)).build(),
            new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.EMAIL_PROVIDER).build());
    //new AuthUI.IdpConfig.Builder(AuthUI.FACEBOOK_PROVIDER).build());
    Intent intent = AuthUI.getInstance()
            .createSignInIntentBuilder()
            .setAvailableProviders(providers).build();
    startActivityForResult(intent,RC_SIGN_IN);
}


protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN){
        IdpResponse idpResponse = IdpResponse.fromResultIntent(data);
        if(idpResponse != null && resultCode == RESULT_OK){
          //  Log.d("currentuser",currentUser.getUid().toString());
            //check if the user is exists by userUID. if he is it jumps to main activity
            refToUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    if(dataSnapshot.hasChild(currentUser.getUid())){

                        Intent mainActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                        mainActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(mainActivity);
                    }else{
                        //if the user is not exists it will move to register activity
                        Intent registerActivity = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
                        registerActivity.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                        startActivity(registerActivity);
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                }
            });



        }else if (idpResponse.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.NO_NETWORK) {
            errorToast("No internet connection");

        }else if (idpResponse.getErrorCode() == ErrorCodes.UNKNOWN_ERROR) {
            errorToast("Unknown Error");
        }
    }
}
```

Here I log in with FirebaseUI. The `refToUsers` is a reference to User lists and I check if the userUID exists. if it does, it will skip the register activity.
if not it will jump to `RegisterActivity`.
For some reason nothing happens. It just skips the whole `refToUser` event listener.
I dont know what's the reason.

Maybe you guys have a better solution for me?

And also I want to show data in RecyclerView from FirebaseDatabase that are stored there. It should be effected if the user is logged in or not

Comment: is it entering onActivityResult? double check that this `child(Params.USERS);` is in your database